Setting up PromQL expression for VMRule
I am trying to implement VMRule which will alert when some pod, deployment, daemonset, statefulset or namespace, which name contains 'tmp' substring, will be detected. But I am not sure if it is a proper expression to solve the task described above. Maybe somebody have an ideas?
apiVersion: operator.victoriametrics.com/v1beta1
kind: VMRule
metadata:
  name: tmp-instance-detected
  labels:
    project: main
spec:
  groups:
  - name: vm-health
    rules:
      - alert: TmpInstanceDetected
        expr: changes(process_start_time_seconds{job=~".*tmp.*", kubernetes="*"}[15m]) > 0
        labels:
          severity: S3
        annotations:
          summary: "Tmp instance detected: {{ $labels.job }} (pod {{ $labels.pod }})"
          description: "A job or instance with 'tmp' in its name (instance {{ $labels.instance }}, pod {{ $labels.pod }}) has been detected."


The expression looks good except kubernetes="*". Are you sure it should be like this, and not like kubernetes=~".*"?
The expression will trigger if any new job with tmp word in its value will be written to VictoriaMetrics. It will continue returning > 0 value up to 15min.

I don't know about VictoriaMetrics, but in Prometheus selector kubernetes=~".*" doesn't make any sense and can be omitted altogether - it'll match any value, including empty one (which is equivalent to absence of label).

It works the same in VictoriaMetrics. My point was that it is unlikely there is a kubernetes label with * value. So it is likely a typo in query.
